# Is it inefficient to only override a method and only call super?

Tags: objective-c, performance, super

Do I take a performance hit by leaving code like the following in my app?

```
- (void)viewDidUnload 
{
  [super viewDidUnload];
  // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
  // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
```

I think the answer is yes, because it results in an unnecessary method call. But I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking about an extra method call, then the answer is yes, there would be a completely unnecessary call in the chain of method invocations leading to the call of the "real" `viewDidUnload`.

I would not go so far as to call removal of such methods an elimination of "performance hits": it is rather unlikely that you or your end-users would notice the effects of such micro-optimization.

Comment: But removing it from the code base cleans up my code significantly.